# In Oracle Apex in an Interactive Grid, how do you update a value in a column based on the value the user chose in another column?

Tags: oracle-apex

This is an Interactive Grid called Visit Duration:
[image]

and its source is the following SQL query:

```
Select ROWID,
       CODE,
       (Select odm.First_Name || ' ' || odm.Last_Name from OPC_DOCTORS_MACHINES odm 
       where odm.CODE = ovd.CODE) as DESCRIPTION,
       V_CODE,
       VISIT_DURATION,
       PAIEMENT,
       D_DISCOUNT,
       DISCOUNT
  from OPC_VISIT_DURATION ovd
```

As you can see the IG uses the OPC_VISIT_DURATION table as the main source except for the DESCRIPTION column that uses OPC_DOCTORS_MACHINES as its source. In OPC_VISIT_DURATION, CODE is a foreign key to the table OPC_DOCTORS_MACHINES. So, in the Interactive Grid whenever the user selects a value for the Code column then the cell for the Description column on the same row should get updated with the equivalent value. The problem is I can’t find any way to update the Description column. I’ve tried all types of Dynamic Actions and none of them work.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it that way.

Instead, query would look like this:

```
Select ROWID,
       CODE,
       V_CODE,
       VISIT_DURATION,
       PAIEMENT,
       D_DISCOUNT,
       DISCOUNT
  from OPC_VISIT_DURATION ovd;
```

`code` column's type would be a **Select list** whose query looks like this:

```
select first_name ||' '|| last_name as d,
       code as r
from opc_doctors_machines
order by d
```

Doing so, when you query interactive grid, you'd see description which correlates to currently stored `code` value.

If you decide to change code, you'd double-click the code cell. List of values would display first/last name (if you want, you can display code itself as well - just concatenate it in LOV query), you'd choose whichever new value you want and save changes. Interactive grid would already show new value.

So, no dynamic actions, lookup tables, etc. If possible, keep it simple for your own benefit, as well as of anyone who will have to maintain your code some day.

Comment: Thanks but I was requested to do it the way instructed in the OP.